# Can't create Edge Cache Origin. Im getting ERROR

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Im trying to create a Edge Cache origin in google cloud shell but im getting error.

`gcloud edge-cache origins create cme-origin \ --origin-address="gs://live-streaming-storage-$LOGNAME"`

ERROR: (gcloud.edge-cache.origins.create) NOT_FOUND: Method not found.

Also tried with gcloud alpha edge-cache origins create, still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact Google beforehand as per link

https://cloud.google.com/media-cdn/docs/overview#request-access

Have the following handy when doing so

- What workloads are you looking for Media CDN to support (ex: VOD,
  Live streaming, UCG, gaming downloads, etc.)
- What are your specific use case and requirements?
- What is the volume of traffic you currently have today (GB/mo or
  PB/mo) or expect to have?”